# Parse Cloud Code fails to assign password to user

Tags: javascript, parsing, parse-platform

I have this Cloud Function on my Parse app:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("assignPasswordToUser", function(request, response){
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("email", request.params.email);
    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            if (results) {
                Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
                var password = request.params.password;
                console.log(results);
                results[0].setPassword(password);
                response.success(1);
            };
        },
        error: function(){
            response.error("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

My iOS app log shows the success code (1), however when I check my User class on Data Browser, the password I passed to the Cloud Function's not set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say that "when I check my User class on the Data Browser, the password I passed to the Cloud Function's not set", are you expecting to see the raw password there? The only way to check if the password is set correctly would be to try and login as that user with the new password.

Comment: @TimothyWalters I did, and It didn't seem to work. I ended up using a work-around, leaving Cloud Code off the table.

Comment: Do you call save() on user object?

Comment: @AkimKhalilov — Yes, actually here's my new code: https://parse.com/questions/assign-parseuser-password-from-cloud-code (which still doesn't work).

Comment: Hi Oscar, I tried your new code and it seem work. Just remove or comment the row: //console.log("setPassword: " + theUser.setPassword(newPassword));